# Select and unselect table cells html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in my website. I need the cell color to change when the user clicks on it and return to the default color on a second click. I have accomplished the first part but dont know how to revert back to default color on a second click.

```
<head>    
     <script type="text/javascript">
   function ChangeColor(tableRow, highLight)
   {
     if (highLight)
     {
       tableRow.style.backgroundColor = '#dcfac9';
     }
     else
     {
       tableRow.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
     }
   }
</head>
<body>
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr onClick="ChangeColor(this, true);" 
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
     </tr>
    <tr onClick="ChangeColor(this, true);">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr onClick="ChangeColor(this, true);">
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the elements by tag name, loop through each `td` and add an event listener.

On click, toggle a class that will add the requested background color.

```js
const tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

Object.values(tds).forEach(td => {
  td.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
});

function changeColor() {
  this.classList.toggle("light-green");
}
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 10px 13px;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.light-green {
  background-color: #dcfac9;
}

.light-green:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing highlight as a parameter to your function,just call your 
function on click with just one as this. Then in the function you can check
the colour of cell and change accordingly.

Or if you want to make it even more generic you can also pass the default 
colour and the new colour to change to.the function will look like this.

```
  function ChangeColour(tableRow, defaultColour, newColour)
    {
      var bg = tableRow.style.backgroundColor;
      if (bg == defaultColour)
     {
        tableRow.style.backgroundColor = newColour;
     }
      else
    {
         tableRow.style.backgroundColor = defaultColour;
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a css class like 
    .highlight { background-color: '#dcfac9'}

and then, in javascript, call .toggleClass('highlight') on click of the row.

Answer (score 0):

As @Devasayal said above `toggleClass` is the best solution for you...

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SN8U3/1/)***</kbd>
*Javascript code*

```
function ChangeColor(elem) {
    if (elem.className != "highlight") {
        elem.className = "highlight";
    } else {
        elem.className = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class instead. Create a few simple functions to add, remove and toggle the class:

```
function hasClass(el, className) {
  return (' ' + el.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') != -1;  
}

function addClass(el, className) {
  if (!hasClass(el, className)) {
    el.className += (el.className? ' ' : '') + className;
  } 
}

function removeClass(el, className) {
  if (hasClass(el, className)) {
    el.className = (' ' + el.className + ' ').replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
  }
}

function toggleClass(el, className) {
  hasClass(el, className)? removeClass(el, className) : addClass(el, className);
}
```

Then, given a class like:

```
.red { background-color: red;}
```

Use them like:

```
<div id="d0">red</div>
<button onclick="toggleClass(document.getElementById('d0'), 'red')">Toggle red</button>
```